# Wait for either a button press or a message response in nextcord

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

i need a function, let's call it `button_or_text`. this function returns a certain value if a button is pressed, most likely a `str`. it returns the `Message` object for a message has been sent.

what i tried doing:

```
import nextcord
import nextcord.ext.commands as cmds

class Coggers(cmds.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @cmds.command()
    async def test(self, ctx: cmds.Context):
        async def button_or_text():
            class Buttons(nextcord.ui.View):
                def __init__(self):
                    super().__init__()
                    self.value = None
                
                @nextcord.ui.button(label="very mysterious button", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green)
                async def very_mysterious_button(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interact: nextcord.Interaction):
                    self.stop()
                    # insert function that somehow cancels the wait_for()
                    # return "some value"
        
            view = Buttons()
            await ctx.send("press this very mysterious button or send a message?", view=view)

            check = lambda msg: ctx.author.id == msg.author.id
            message = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)

            return message.content

        
        print(await button_or_text())
        await ctx.send("end")


def setup(bot: cmds.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Coggers(bot))
```

here i did a `wait_for` for the function. if a button was pressed, somehow cancel that `wait_for` then return the set value for pressing a button. if a message was sent, somehow stop the `Buttons` object from listening then return the `Message` object.

i'm scratching my head on how to do both the `wait_for` cancel and the return, but i feel like this isn't the best way of doing it and i'm missing a more "elegant" way

any help?

Comment: So you are trying to simultaneously check for a button press and a message? You should use `asyncio` to do this. I would look into `asyncio.wait`. I would learn a little about coroutines before getting into this as it can be very confusing. I did some digging and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KV5174e2Q0&t=311s) youtube video should help.

Comment: thank you Roopesh, i will try to understand coroutines more. i wasn't familliar of it a lot so i needed to ask a question.

Comment: Once you get them, it's a game changer. Goodluck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without all details as to what exactly you want to achieve it's hard to give a comprehensive solution, but here's the general idea of how to wait for the first of two events simultaneously:

```py
async def await_input(self):
    """waits for valid user input (message, button) and returns the corresponding payload
    """

    events = [
        self.bot.client.wait_for('message', check=self._check_msg),
        self.bot.client.wait_for('interaction', check=self._check_button)
    ]

    # with asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, this triggers as soon as one of the events is fired
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(events, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    event = done.pop().result()

    # cancel the other check
    for future in pending:
        future.cancel()

    # check if the event has the `application_id` attribute to determine if it was the button press or a message
    if hasattr(event, 'application_id'):
        return 'button pressed'  # or whatever you want to return there
    else:
        return event  # this will be the message
```

What's left for you to do is to implement the `_check_msg` (this can most likely be the lambda you already have) and `_check_button` to make sure you're only getting input you are interested in. You might also want to set a timeout for each of the events unless you want to wait indefinitely

Comment: nice! i was going to use this with 2 buttons though, checking for either button press or a message, but it's my mistake to not include it in the question as i'm trying to keep things simple. i know how to go off of this though, thank you for the answer!

Comment: yeah this code should be a pretty solid base to go off of. Also even if you have two buttons, you only need to wait for one of them to be pressed. Then after just check the id or value of the button.